# Select2 jQuery Plugin: Is there a way to sort a list of tags alphabetically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using Select2 plugin (http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) and as you can see by the list of tags I have in the screenshot, they aren't listed alphabetically and I'd like to be able to do so.

[image]

EDIT: This is what I currently have, but instead of query, I want to sort the data (@appTags) via 'text', not 'id':

```
scope.find('input[name=noun]').select2({
  data: @appTags,
  sortResults: function(results, container, query) {
    if (query.term) {
      return results.sort();
    }
    return results;
  }
});
```

Screenshots of my Console paused in Debugger:

[image]

Here's an image of the @appTags object, of which I'd like to sort via 'text':

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a bit of code from the docs that is using the JS built in sort function. I modified it to sort alphabetically instead of by length as they did in the docs.

```
$('#e22').select2({
    sortResults: function(results, container, query) {
        if (query.term) {
            // use the built in javascript sort function
            return results.sort();
        }
        return results;
    }
});
```

Comment: How would I edit this so instead of using query, I've got data from the server? `scope.find('input[name=noun]').select2({
        data: @appTags,
        placeholder: 'Tag',
        sortResults: (results, container, query) ->
          # use the built in javascript sort function
          return results.sort()  if query.term
          results
      })` At present, the solution you posed didn't work in this case. Do I change query to data?

Comment: The spacing on what you posted makes it a bit difficult to read. Are you using coffeescript? If you can try to post it again with the right spacing that you have, we can see what the problem is, but from the current post it seems that some things are just out of order.

Comment: Just added the code in above in JS, rather than Coffeescript. Hope you're able to help! Cheers

Comment: Hard for me to test right now, but since you always want sorted results, try this which should just always sort the results, I think the example that included query.term was sorting only after some search text was entered.

    `$('#e22').select2({
        sortResults: function(results) {
            return results.sort();
        }
    });`

Comment: Tried that but no luck and tried variations of that as well to no avail. If you manage to get it working with data: @appTags, I'd love to know.

Comment: I've edited the question above with more screenshots of the @appTags object, which I want to sort on 'text'.

Comment: As of Select2 version 4.0, this option is now called `sorter`.

Answer (score 3):

For select2 plugin version 4.0

```
var customSorter = function(data) {
     return data.sort(function(a,b){
         a = a.text.toLowerCase();
         b = b.text.toLowerCase();
         if(a > b) {
             return 1;
         } else if (a < b) {
             return -1;
         }
         return 0;
     });
};
```

In select2 version 4.0, the sort param name is changed to "sorter"
Now pass "customSorter" to the plugin

> $("#genre").select2({ tags: true, sorter: customSorter});

Answer (score 1):

## Select2 API v3.x (`sortResults`)

You can sort elements using `sortResults` callback option with [`String.localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/localeCompare) which uses case non sensitive comparison:

```js
let tags = [ { id: 0, text: 'androidtag' }, { id: 1, text: 'origin' }, { id: 2, text: 'Hobby' }, { id: 3, text: 'is-awesome' }, { id: 4, text: 'age' }, { id: 5, text: 'TestingDateTag' }, { id: 6, text: 'name' }, { id: 7, text: 'surname' }, { id: 8, text: 'Birthday' } ];

$( 'input[name=noum]' ).select2({
  data: tags,
  tags: true,
  /* Sort tags using case non sensitive comparison */
  sortResults: data => data.sort((a, b) => a.text.localeCompare(b.text)),
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.4/select2.min.css" integrity="sha256-ijlUKKj3hJCiiT2HWo1kqkI79NTEYpzOsw5Rs3k42dI=" crossorigin="anonymous" /><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.4/select2.min.js" integrity="sha256-7A2MDY2eGSSUvgfbuH1IdzYk8qkEd3uzwiXADqPDdtY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input name="noum" style="width: 200px" />
```

## Select2 [API v4.0 (`sorter`)](https://select2.org/configuration/options-api)

You can sort elements using `sorter` callback option **with an empty `<select>` tag**:

```js
let tags = [ { id: 0, text: 'androidtag' }, { id: 1, text: 'origin' }, { id: 2, text: 'Hobby' }, { id: 3, text: 'is-awesome' }, { id: 4, text: 'age' }, { id: 5, text: 'TestingDateTag' }, { id: 6, text: 'name' }, { id: 7, text: 'surname' }, { id: 8, text: 'Birthday' } ];

$( 'select[name=noum]' ).select2({
  data: tags,
  tags: true,
  /* Sort tags using case non sensitive comparison */
  sorter: data => data.sort((a, b) => a.text.localeCompare(b.text)),
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.css" integrity="sha256-xqxV4FDj5tslOz6MV13pdnXgf63lJwViadn//ciKmIs=" crossorigin="anonymous" /><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js" integrity="sha256-FA14tBI8v+/1BtcH9XtJpcNbComBEpdawUZA6BPXRVw=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<select name="noum" style="width: 200px" multiple="multiple" />
```