# angular-ui/ui-select dropdown start with

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-select

is that possible to show items in drodown as per start with?

i am using this https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select , and from drop down, if i write "a" it show all words which have "a"

i wanted to show only words which start with "a"

there is directive, https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select-match, but not able to figure out how to do it

http://embed.plnkr.co/WyIC087njDHLmIVGTAj7/preview

i want same thing in angular.js: [Select2 jQuery Plugin: Is there a way to sort a list of tags alphabetically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520524/select2-jquery-plugin-is-there-a-way-to-sort-a-list-of-tags-alphabetically)

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to tweak this a little bit but...

You could write a custom filter function that returns true if the first char is "a":

```
    <ui-select ng-model="card.id">
    <ui-select-match>{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="item.id as item in users | filter:criteriaMatch($select.search)">
        <div ng-bind-html="item.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Then in the javascript do something like:

```
$scope.criteriaMatch = function( s ) {
  return function(val) {
    val.charAt(0) == s;
  }
};
```

Comment: Ok, but it is not about at only "a" :)

Comment: this still works ...just mod it a little bit and change what you pass to the function ... pass $select.search to the filter function instead ... see my edit. So what you're doing now is returning a higher order function in order to pass a value to the filter function yourself in addition to the value of the item